# Microsoft Azure Startup Task Not Executing

Tags: azure, startup, azure-web-roles

I have a simple file in the root of my Web project (which is tied to a Web worker role).  The file is named `Startup.cmd`. This file contains the following line:  `dir > directory.txt`.  It executes properly when I run it from the command line and outputs a list of the directory contents to file named `directory.txt` as you would expect.  Similarly, the line `ECHO Write this line to file > output.txt` does not appear to work either.

Inside `ServiceDefinition.csdef` for my Azure Cloud Service project, I have the following lines:

```
<WebRole name="Website" vmsize="Small">
    <Startup>
        <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple"></Task>
    </Startup>
    ....
</WebRole>
```

I believe it is finding the file, because I have tried changing the path and it will throw a build error that it cannot find it.  The issue is that when I check my `/bin/` directory after debugging to the Azure Debugging Environment, I see `Startup.cmd` (I have it set to `Copy always`) but I do not see `directory.txt`.  I'm not sure of another way to confirm that it executed properly.

Comment: worth reading: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cclayton/archive/2012/05/17/windows-azure-start-up-tasks-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following MSDN article useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180155.aspx.

As a result, I made some changes to my `Startup.cmd` file. I changed the command to:

```
ECHO The current version is %MyVersionNumber% >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
EXIT /B 0
```

However, this did not appear to put the output in my temporary directory for my system: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp`. I'm going to presume this is because the Azure Compute Emulator uses a different temp directory I am unaware of.

I changed my `Startup.cmd` to:

```
ECHO The current version is %MyVersionNumber% >> "c:\temp\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
EXIT /B 0
```

And updated my configuration to:

```
<WebRole name="Website" vmsize="Small">
  <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
          <Environment>
              <Variable name="MyVersionNumber" value="1.0.0.0" />
              <Variable name="ComputeEmulatorRunning">
                  <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
              </Variable>
          </Environment>
      </Task>
  </Startup>
  ...
</WebRole>
```

And this did appear to write the file to `C:\temp\` upon starting the debugger.

Comment: sample folder structure for the initial cmd 

C:\Resources\temp\24eb9559640c4fc0be2798ff81064a3c.myclient\RoleTemp\StartupLog.txt